# Converting WKB to WKT

Tags: convert, well-known-text, well-known-binary

How can I convert WKB to WKT form?

I stored coordinates  in WKB but now I  want to display it using WKT form.

Comment: Hi tina, you'll need to provide more details to make this question answerable, such as what software are you attempting to do this with, or attempting to do encoding / decoding directly?

Comment: Consider changing the question title to "Converting WKB to WKT"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to use PostGIS to do the conversion, you can choose from the following functions:

```
bytea WKB = ST_AsBinary(geometry);
text WKT = ST_AsText(geometry);
geometry = ST_GeomFromWKB(bytea WKB, SRID);
geometry = ST_GeometryFromText(text WKT, SRID);
```

More: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch04.html#OpenGISWKBWKT

Comment: no i am not using any exisitng db,. i want to apply spatial db ..

Comment: "i want to apply spatial db" - Does that mean you want to use PostGIS? Then the above functions should help.

Comment: This helped me solve it for SQL Server. In SQL Server the function is [`STAsText`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933970.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

If you can work with Java, the [JTS Topology Suite](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/) can perform such translation by using the classes *com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKBReader* and *com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry*. A code like this should get the geometry in Well-Known Text format:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKBReader;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;

String wkbString = "0101000000cdcccccc170d2241b81e859bcb405241";
// geometry in WKB format to be translated to WKT
byte[] aux = WKBReader.hexToBytes(wkbString);
Geometry geom = new WKBReader().read(aux);
String wktString = geom.toText();
// geometry in WKT format
System.out.printf("WKB = %s\n", wkbString);
System.out.printf("WKT = %s\n", wktString);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Sql Server Spatial

```
select geometry::STGeomFromWKB(0x01030000000100000005000000E968ED3E66CF1D41BD6859D5EEE15941E968ED3E66CF1D41844B22F8E1E959417156F69608241F41844B22F8E1E959417156F69608241F41BD6859D5EEE15941E968ED3E66CF1D41BD6859D5EEE15941,3857).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using R, you can convert between WKB and WKT using the packages [rgeos](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rgeos) and [wkb](http://cran.r-project.org/package=wkb). Example:

```
# load packages
library(rgeos)
library(wkb)

# create raw vector representing WKB geometry
wkb <- hex2raw("0101000000cdcccccc170d2241b81e859bcb405241")

# convert WKB to Spatial object
obj <- readWKB(wkb)

# convert Spatial object to WKT
wkt <- writeWKT(obj, byid = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install any tools, online conversions between WKB, WKT and GeoJSON formats can be performed using [Online conversion between geometric formats](https://rodic.fr/blog/online-conversion-between-geometric-formats/).

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin and PostGIS Java, net.postgis.jdbc.PGgeometry can take WKB representation:

```
val wkb = "010100000033333333333324409a99999999992440"
val geometry = PGgeometry(wkb)
```