# How to transform this PostGIS type of projection to EPSG:900913 in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, coordinate-system

I have transferred this kind of projection from this type(which I don't what type it is):

```
010100000054E077E6F8F33640FD87F4DBD7AD4340
```

to EPSG:900913. I have the points which are in the above format in OpenLayers I just don't know the projection type so I can fidn the right command to change it.

So I am asking for both the type of the projection and any commands that will change it to ESPG:9000913 and add it to my layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess would be EPSG:4326 WGS84 lon/lat degrees.

Similar to this question: [Import Points with WKB format to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69500/import-points-with-wkb-format-to-qgis) I imported the data into QGIS using the QuickWKT plugin, and the point ends up in the Greek town of Volos:

[image]

If you have a postgis database attached to QGIS, you can simply copy and paste the point into an existing Postgis table of type point.

Or use one of the methods described here:

[How to convert WKB to WKT?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3808/converting-wkb-to-wkt)

Comment: Right that is about where I want to be. Let me check this answer further!

Comment: It is a good answer but I want to add it to an online map on the OpenLayers API so I would need to know what projection is this exactly? WKT? WKB?

Comment: The projection is EPSG:4326 WGS84, format is WKB. Since Openlayers can not read WKB, you have to use postgis functions to convert it to degree coordinates, as mentioned in the linked question. WGS84 is supported by Openlayers by default.