# Understanding the format: WKB from WKT and how to convert the first into the latter

Tags: postgis, convert, well-known-text, well-known-binary

I don't understand which kind of format I have my data. The column name is *wkb_geom*, so I supposed that data were in WKB format, but then I was checking around and I couldn't find example of it. Data are like this:

`"0106000020E6100000010000000103000000010000007218000007000060B1D42B4010000060A372454007000060B1D42B40030000009D724540030000E0D5D42B40030000009D724540030000E0D5D42B40050000C08A7245400B000040FAD42B40050000C08A7245400B000040FAD42B40130000807B7245400B000040FAD4 (...)`"

Is it in WKB or WKT format?? Second question, in case it's in WKB format, how can I convert it into WKT format? I was trying to follow this suggestion

[How to convert WKB to WKT?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3808/converting-wkb-to-wkt)

so the query is

```
UPDATE "ita_adm1"
SET wkb_geometry  = ST_GeomFromWKB("wkb_geometry",4326)
```

but it keeps saying that the function ST_GeomFromWKB doesn't exist.

Comment: That's a hexadecimal dump of WKB, not WKB itself.

Comment: What software environment are you using?  Is it PostGIS as per the example or something else?.  Also, if you are using Postgresql, do you have PostGIS installed (it is not a standard part of Postgresql - which could explain why the function is missing - can you confirm?  Finally PostGIS stores geometry in a hexadecimal format (note Vince's comment), so have you tried ST_AsText?

Comment: yes I use PostGIS with the postgreSQL environment. I have tried that one too as it was suggested in the thread I already followed...Paul Ramsey's functions I've tried them all..

Btw with that query

UPDATE "ita_adm1"
SET wkb_geometry  = ST_AsText("wkb_geometry")

that's the error I get

ERRORE:  Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is called hex-encoded WKB. This specific example is the [extended version](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/master/doc/ZMSgeoms.txt), called EWKB, since it has SRID=4326 as found by `E6100000`.

WKB can be viewed in a few forms. The hex-encoded string representation is the most common, which if it is actually text can be converted using a simple `::geometry` cast:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(wkb_geometry), ST_AsEWKT(wkb_geometry)
FROM (
  SELECT '0106000020620D000001000000010300000001000000040000000000000'
  '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F03F000000000'
  '0000040000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000'::geometry AS wkb_geometry
) AS f;
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------------------------------------
st_astext | MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,0 1,2 2,0 0)))
st_asewkt | SRID=3426;MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,0 1,2 2,0 0)))
```

Only use [ST_GeomFromWKB](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromWKB.html) if it is a raw `bytea` binary stream.

Furthermore, when geometry data is selected from a PostGIS database, the hex-encoded EWKB representation is shown in the query result. To get WKT or EWKT representations, use the [ST_AsText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) or [ST_AsEWKT](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html) functions, as demonstrated above.