# Finding relation between Nominatim row and gb_postcode table row?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, geometry, nominatim

Currently I have PgAdmin 3 open with a copy of the Nominatim DB I processed on a Linux virtual machine. I imported the `gb_postcode.sql` database successfully from the Nominatim documentation but I'm struggling to find a way to match a row in my main `placex` table in Nominatim to my `gb_postcode` table that's been imported.

Both tables provide a Geometry row, of which I tried using `ST_Intersection` on but the result was beyond inaccurate (returned 1.6m records rather than a single one, or a small subset of data).

Is there any way currently that will allow me to find a relationship between a Geometry object in a Nominatim record (such as `0102000020E61000000500000014A5CEED6F5A01C07D6F78E68A1A4A4091E398767B5A01C08A517C21891A4A404221020EA15A01C02E05FFB6821A4A405698631E9E5A01C0CBC1C7BB7E1A4A40A53D14BB6C5A01C026A36F777B1A4A40`) and the Geometry object in the `gb_postcode` table (such as `0101000020E61000005D96EA24715B01C0A76FB0828F1A4A40`)?

For examples sake, these two Geometry values are matching for the same street in the UK, but I'm struggling to relate them programmatically.

*Sample postcode data*:

`ID - Postcode - Geometry`

`627881;"HG4 3NJ";"0101000020E610000023F05E6B62D4F9BF9C759A1C19134B40"
627882;"HG4 3NL";"0101000020E6100000EAA10AA1EAEEF9BFBEA275E3EF134B40"
627883;"HG4 3NN";"0101000020E6100000AE7E4727E1F1F9BF4AE5506C06134B40"`

Comment: Crossposted: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/52367/finding-relation-between-nominatim-row-and-gb_postcode-table-row

Comment: are gb_postcodes in British National Grid or lat/lng WGS84?

Comment: I'm honestly not entirely sure @Mapperz, I'll edit in a sample of the data to the OP, I'd appreciate it if you could tell me which one it is.

Comment: convert your Binary WKB to text http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146266/understanding-the-format-wkb-from-wkt-and-how-to-convert-the-first-into-the-latinto-the-lat using ST_GeomFromWKB