# Conversion of a GeoJSON into EWKB format?

Tags: python, shapely, well-known-binary

I see libraries such as `shape` from `shapely.geometry` that support conversion to WKB and WKT binaries. What I am unable to find is guidance on converting to EWKB specifically.

I suspect this is because libraries that support WKB conversion also support EWKB? How do I know if I am creating an EWKB vs WKB? Are all WKB also EWKB (but not the other way around)?

If EWKB is an extension of WKB, how would I check that, say, Shapely, supports EWKB format?

I am trying to understand if EWKB is standard or something that was just built for PostGIS (where I have seen it used) and how I can make sure that data I am producing for a function that expects EWKB can be correctly formatted.

Because of @shongololo's comment, I wanted to add a snippet of what I am going presently to generate the WKB of the shape from GeoJSON.

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
import binascii
# convert geom to wkb format
geom_str = json.dumps(route['geometry'])
geom_geo = geojson.loads(geom_str)
geom_shp = shape(geom_geo)
geom_wkb = geom_shp.to_wkb()
geom_cln = binascii.hexlify(geom_wkb).decode('ascii')
```

Comment: With shapely use the wkb module and set the hex option to true, e.g. wkb.loads(geom, hex=true)

Comment: Thanks @shongololo - Any chance you could elaborate on what including the hex boolean as a parameter is doing? Looks like you are using a library wkb? Is that from Shapely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shapely is based on GEOS, which natively reads/writes EWKB. The Z-dimension support of EWKB (different from ISO) is well supported by GEOS/Shapely, but getting/setting SRIDs is a hidden feature. Here's a quick demo:

```
from shapely import geos, wkb, wkt

# Show EWKB
p = wkt.loads('POINT Z(1 2 3)')
print(p.wkb_hex)  # This is little endian EWKB with just PointZ bit set
# 0101000080000000000000F03F00000000000000400000000000000840

# Change a the default mode to add this, if SRID is set
geos.WKBWriter.defaults['include_srid'] = True

# Get/Set SRID
print(geos.lgeos.GEOSGetSRID(p._geom))  # 0, or unset
# Set it to EPSG:4326
geos.lgeos.GEOSSetSRID(p._geom, 4326)
print(p.wkb_hex)  # This is little endian EWKB with SRID and PointZ bit set
# 01010000A0E6100000000000000000F03F00000000000000400000000000000840

# And for fun, change the output to big endian
geos.WKBWriter.defaults['big_endian'] = True
print(p.wkb_hex)
# 00A0000001000010E63FF000000000000040000000000000004008000000000000
```

Note that if SRID is not used and the geometries are simple 2D, then ISO WKB and EWKB are the same.

Comment: Thanks, this is a terrific answer. I hope it wasn't "bad form" to switch this to the best answer, but it most directly addresses the question and provides examples that are immediately applicable.

Answer (score 1):

To respond to your question

> Any chance you could elaborate on what including the hex boolean as a parameter is doing?

It is returning a hex encoded string. The module he referred to (`wkb`) is a shapely module.

Here is the [documentation](http://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.html#module-shapely.wkb) page for shapely. You can search the page (ctrl+f) for `shapely.wkb.loads`.

For posterity, the question quoted above was in response to an answer by shongololo.

> With shapely use the wkb module and set the hex option to true, e.g.
>   wkb.loads(geom, hex=true) – shongololo

Comment: Thanks. And when hex is true, the product is a EWKB file? Does that mean that all EWKB is is WKB hex encoded?

I had a "hunch" that SRID inclusion was also a component of EWKB and is not included in WKB by default. Any chance this is true or what I am saying even makes sense in that regard?

Comment: I believe that hex-encoded WKB is EWKB. I think you are also correct in thinking that EWKB has an SRID. Here is a link to another [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146266/understanding-the-format-wkb-from-wkt-and-how-to-convert-the-first-into-the-lat). The first answer explains a lot about EWKB. I would also suggest looking at the linked information from the answer.

Comment: No, hex-encoded WKB is just a non-binary representation of WKB. EWKB can include a SRID. https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#EWKB_EWKT