# Converting Latitude/Longitude to WKB with Python

Tags: python, geometry, convert, well-known-binary

I have a CSV containing longitude and latitude and was wondering how I can use python to convert them to WKB to provide me with location data?

I know it can be done in PostgreSQL using `UPDATE mytable SET geog = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat), 4326)::geography`, but I'm wondering if python has an equivalent?

For example I need to convert
`Latitude': 55.20394960316738, 'Longitude': -2.5378432182396935` to `0101000000804263E5719F20C0508E2C4901E94940`

Comment: [Conversion of a GeoJSON into EWKB format?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/226912/2581)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusing [including SRID in WKBWriter in Shapely doesn't work](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290769/including-srid-in-wkbwriter-in-shapely-doesnt-work)

```py
from shapely import wkb, wkt
g = wkt.loads('POINT(-2.5378432182396935 55.20394960316738)')
wkb.dumps(g, hex=True, srid=4326)
# returns
# 0101000020E610000010B8C5BE804D04C06BD145051B9A4B40
```

You mentioned

> For example I need to convert 'Latitude': 55.20394960316738, 'Longitude': -2.5378432182396935 to 0101000000804263E5719F20C0508E2C4901E94940

FYI, you made a mistake e.g running `SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-2.5378432182396935, 55.20394960316738), 4326)::geography;` returns `0101000020E610000010B8C5BE804D04C06BD145051B9A4B40` and not `0101000000804263E5719F20C0508E2C4901E94940`

Comment: Thanks! And apologies for the error in the geometry which I copied and pasted into my question