# How SRID is represented as part of EWKB

Tags: postgis, well-known-binary

I am trying to find the spec that defines how the SRID metadata is included as part of EWKB in PostGIS.

Which bytes/hex values represent the SRID metadata in EWKB? Where can I find a spec on EWKB apart from this [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#EWKB_EWKT) (which doesn't say about the byte level details)? How is EWKB different from OGC WKB?

Comment: Maybe answered in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146266/understanding-the-format-wkb-from-wkt-and-how-to-convert-the-first-into-the-lat that gives a link to https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/master/doc/ZMSgeoms.txt.

Answer (score 4):

The "Extensions to Well-Known-Binary format" in PostGIS are documented in https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/master/doc/ZMSgeoms.txt

Excerpt from the document:

```
If the SRID flag is set it's value is encoded as a 4byte integer
right after the type integer.

If only wkbZ or wkbM flags are set Point coordinates will
be XYZ or XYM, if both wkbZ and wkbM flags are set Point
coordinates will be XYZM (Z first).

For example, a ZM-Point geometry at the location (10,20) with Z==30,
M==40 and SRID=4326 would be:

WKBPoint {

    byte    byteOrder;      // wkbXDR or wkbNDR

    uint32  wkbType;        // (wkbPoint+wkbZ+wkbM+wkbSRID) =
                    // 0xE0000001

    uint32  SRID;           // 4326

    Point {
        Double    x;    // 10.0
        Double    y;    // 20.0
        Double    z;    // 30.0
        Double    m;    // 40.0
    }
}
```